# What is the array output type here

Tags: javascript, php

On line 24 where I test if the `test2[1] == "invalid"` never works it always goes to the else and takes me to the next page. I think `test2[1]` just isn't a string but I don't know what else it would be please help

```
function login() {
      var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
      var passW = document.getElementById("password").value;

      if (email == "" || passW == "") {
        alert("Please enter a valid email or password.");
      } else {
        var myXMLRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        myXMLRequest.onload = openWorkout;
        var url = "assignment10.php?em=" + email + "&pass=" + passW;
        myXMLRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        myXMLRequest.send();
      }
    }

    function openWorkout() {
      var invalid = "invalid";
      var step = this.responseText;
      var test = step.split(",");
      var test2 = test[0].split(":");
      console.log(step);
      console.log(test);
      console.log(test2[1]);
      if (test2[1] == "invalid") {
        alert("The email or password you entered is invalid. Please try again.");
      } else {
        window.location = "#workoutPage";
      }
    }

    <?php
    //TASK 1: MAKE A CONNECTION TO THE DATABASE, DISPLAY ERROR FOR FAILED CONNECTIONS
    //(FOR GODADDY) NOTE: $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "database", 3306);

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "User", "1234", "ass10");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    //CHECK IF EMAIL AND ENTERED PASSWORD VALID (LOGIN PAGE [first part of open workout checks login password])
    $entEmail = $_GET['em'];
    $entPassword = $_GET['pass'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM membership_table WHERE Email = $entEmail, Password = $entPassword";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {
         $data = "invalid";
    } else {
        $data = "valid";
    }


    //Pass to JSON
    $json = array(
        "data" => $data,
        "Email" => $entEmail,
        "Password" => $entPassword

    );

    header("Contenttype:Application/json");
    print(json_encode($json));
    ?>
```

**here are the console.log outputs on lines 21 - 23**

```
assignment10.js:21 {"data":"invalid","Email":"q","Password":"1"}
assignment10.js:22 (3) ["{"data":"invalid"", ""Email":"q"", ""Password":"1"}"]
assignment10.js:23 "invalid"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning JSON from your PHP, so process it as that using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), rather than trying to split the string apart:

```
var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var test = response.data;
if (test == 'invalid') {
    ...
```

Note the issue with your current code is that `test2[1]` is *literally* `"invalid"`, including the double quotes, so for your test to work you'd need to use

```
if (test2[1] == '"invalid"') {
```

Here's a snippet to demonstrate the code using the output of `console.log(step)` from your question:

```js
const responseText = '{"data":"invalid","Email":"q","Password":"1"}';
var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
var test = response.data;
if (test == 'invalid') {
  console.log('Invalid!');
} else {
  console.log('Valid!');
}
```